# Is android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW for maps unusable or am I wrong?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, marker

What I do with my application is allowing users to discover POI on Google Maps.
That's really easy and I use

```
final Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:+"
    + lat+ ","
    + lon));
startActivity(myIntent);
```

I have 2 big issues with this

1) When Latitude is activated, Google Maps open and show my location instead of my POI location!
I have to quit Google Maps and come back again to focus on my POI location.

2) There are no marker on my POI location! such a shame, if I move a little bit the Map, My POI is lost.

So my question are: do you have the same feeling than me with this intent? Is there some workaround to fix that? (maybe an other intent)?

Thank a lot for any help, I think I will have to create my own MapActivity and I think that's a waste of time for such a little feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

`final Intent myIntent = new Intent(
    android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse( "geo:0,0?q=" + lat + "," + lon )
);
startActivity(myIntent)`